# Using JS to pull through other pages without a refresh

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JS, currently on a course that is going through JS etc.

I have my online portfolio that I am working on. Currently I have my homepage (landing page all dev'ed up and working). There are CSS animations that are running on the page and at the end of the animation I am wanting it to wait 30 seconds and then for the page to transition nicely over to my work page.

I don't have a problem with the CSS animation's etc. What I am trying to research is the best way to use JS to pull my work page without it refreshing the page. My mentor mentioned things such as using AJAX requests or something along those lines.

So I am just looking to see if there is a simple solution to secretly load other pages in the background and then pull it through when the time for it comes.

Comment: [`AJAX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX), which uses  [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), is the way to go about it. It does not refresh the whole page, instead only a part of it.

Comment: Sweet, will do some reading on it :)

Comment: Are you allowed to use jQuery ?

Comment: Yea. Been reading up on XMLHTTP and my work friend mentioned jQuery and AJAX and reading up on that now. I got the basics for XMLHTTP but now gonna look more into the jquery.ajax I think it is